# sql query to get the student name with rank between 10 and 20 out of 100 students?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, limit, ranking

i have list of 100 students with there total marks and names.Based on this mark give rank to each students.
i need to find the names of those students whose rank between 10th rank to 20th rank.
students having rank 10,11,12...20 in the ascending order.

Comment: Mysql or Oracle? And do you need to know the rank? or you just want them sorted?

Comment: i just want the names of students who has ranks 10 to 20 in the ascending order of there rank.

Comment: But the implementation is different in mysql and oracle, and if you need to return the rank is even different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT studentName FROM studentTable ORDER BY totalMarks DESC LIMIT 10, 10;
```

Comment: How about if more than one students having same rank?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 SELECT <name> FROM <tablename>
 WHERE <rankfieldname> BETWEEN 10 AND 20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `studentName` FROM `studentTable`
WHERE `rank` BETWEEN 10 AND 20;
```